# Getchar() from client in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, getchar, recv

I am creating a C program that is run from a raspberry pi that can take commands from a telnet terminal (putty) from a client (other PC/Laptop) which is connected through a TCP/IP connection (socket programming) and process those commands to run a motor which is connected to the RPi.
This means I only need to create a server code to be run in the RPi, and not a client code.

My question is, can there be a way so that I can use `getchar()` on the inputs from the client (should only be coded from the server side)? Could it be used with `recv()`?

The reason I need to use `getchar()` is because I have this algorithm in mind that reads each character from the client before they press enter, which allows me to differentiate the clients' commands from the arguments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to read 1 character at a time? Surely reading in all the input and using a loop to traverse the input buffer would be more efficient.

Comment: Getchar() implicitely reads from stdin. You could use plain `read(fd, &ch, 1)` (or read larger chunks) or use fp=fdopen(fd,...) and use getc() on the resulting fp. In any case, you need to buffer the incoming characters until you have seen a `\n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I read the question right your problem is to read input from the client before they press enter.

In that case the answer is no. Even if you jump through the hoops to use getchar on the server side that won't change the client, which will be causing your problem. If the client only sends data when the user presses enter then nothing in the server can fix that.

If that isn't the problem and you only want to read input one char at a time them simply specify a size of 1 for recv(). It will be hugely inefficient but it's not like users type that fast. It only becomes a problem when later users start to script things and want to send many commands per second. Note: You can use fdopen() to create a FILE* from a socket and use getc() to have the libc buffer input for you and have a getchar() equivalent.

Either way getchar() isn't the way to go.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for enlightening me. This is my first project working on TCP/IP stuff so i'm not really familiar with the functions used. Could you maybe give an example of how to use the fdopen() and getc() as you said? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: There really isn't anything to it: `FILE *file = fdopen(fd, "r"); int res = getc(file);`